# Java 7 Kerberos Issue - AES128 Corrupt checksum

Tags: java, linux, active-directory, aes, kerberos

I am migrating from Java 6 to Java 7 and am running into a problem with Kerberos authentication.  It looks to me that the underlying encryption type order is switched and as a result a different encryption type is used.  In this case `Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType` is being used for part of the transaction when Java 7 is run.  `ArcFourHmacEType` is used when Java 6 is run and for the other part of the Java 7 run.

Other details: running on Linux (Fedora 16) against a Windows Active Directory server.

I know I can get authentication to work if I set the default_tkt_enctypes, default_tgs_enctypes, permitted_enctypes parameters in the krb5.conf file; however, I would like to get it to work without having a file at all and ideally without having to force one or two enctypes.

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at *internal.code*.LDAPAuthenticator.authenticate(LDAPAuthenticator.java:46)
at *internal.code*.LDAPAuthenticatorTest.testUpdateUser(LDAPAuthenticatorTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
at junit.textui.TestRunner.doRun(TestRunner.java:116)
at com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.doRun(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:139)
at junit.textui.TestRunner.doRun(TestRunner.java:109)
at com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:52)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:182)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(LdapSasl.java:168)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:232)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2740)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
at *internal.code*.LDAPAuthenticator.getAttributeFor(LDAPAuthenticator.java:156)
at *internal.code*.user.LDAPAuthenticator.access$000(LDAPAuthenticator.java:27)
at *internal.code*.user.LDAPAuthenticator$1.run(LDAPAuthenticator.java:49)
... 27 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(GssKrb5Client.java:328)
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:187)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(LdapSasl.java:132)
... 42 more
Caused by: GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getData(WrapToken_v2.java:151)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getData(WrapToken_v2.java:105)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.unwrap(Krb5Context.java:983)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.unwrap(GSSContextImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(GssKrb5Client.java:234)
... 44 more
```

Is it possible to use AES128 with this setup?

If I can't get AES128 to work, is there a way to set the default enctypes via a system parameter (instead of using krb5.conf)?

Comment: Do you have the unlimited security JAR installed?

Comment: Don't think you should need that for 128-bit AES, just for 256-bit AES, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Java throws an illegal keysize exception typically when you need JCE but don't have it installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to James Cape, install the unlimited security file. Due to US jurisdiction, the JRE cannot be shipped with that JAR.